# Remove multiple children from parent?

Tags: javascript, removechild

I have a bunch on elements with the same name that i am trying to remove at the same time with an onchange function.

Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function removeoldAccounts() {
        var e = document.getElementById("account_table")
        var accounts = document.getElementsByName("extraaccounts");
        e.removeChildren(accounts);
    }
</script>
```

(Not even sure if removeChildren is a real command) And my element that im giving the onchange action to:

```
<select id="piname" name="pi_name" onChange="removeoldAccounts" />
```

And the elements im trying to have removed:

```
<tbody id="account_table">
    <tr>
        <td>Account Number<span>*</span>:</td>

        <td id="accounts">
            <select id="accountnum" name="account_number">
                <option value="5636745946254">5636745946254</option>
                <option value="23164847322">23164847322</option>
            </select> 
        </td>

        <td> 
            <input type="hidden" id="theValue3" value="81">
            <input type="button" value="Add More" onclick="addaccount()">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="80" name="extraaccount">
        <td>
            <select id="80" name="account_number">
                <option value="5636745946254">5636745946254</option>
                <option value="23164847322">23164847322</option>
            </select>
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="text" size="20" name="account_comment80">
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="button" onclick="removeaccount(80)" value="remove">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="81" name="extraaccount">
        <td>
            <select id="81" name="account_number">
                <option value="5636745946254">5636745946254</option>
                <option value="23164847322">23164847322</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size="20" name="account_comment81">
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="button" onclick="removeaccount(81)" value="remove">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Sorry if the html is a bit sloppy but basically, a `tbody` with a bunch of `td`s that have the same name ( extraaccount)

Comment: Sorry... _What_ are you trying to do? Also, on editing your JavaScript I noticed there was a missing semicolon on `var e = document.getElementById("account_table")`. Try that, and look in your browser's error console for errors too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function removeoldAccounts() {
    var accounts = document.getElementsByName("extraaccounts");
    var account;
    var parent;
    for (account in accounts) {
       parent = account.parentNode;
       parent.removeChild(account);
    }
}
</script>
```

and...

```
<select id="piname" name="pi_name" onChange="removeoldAccounts();" />
```

Comment: Hmm that looked like it would work but it didnt..no errors.. are you sure theres no simple mistake like forgetting an s at the end or something (I dont know javascript well enough to catch these small errors)

Comment: Yeah i realized that part was wrong so now i get the following error: "parentNode is undefined" (parentNode.removeChild..)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
if ( e.hasChildNodes() )
{
    for(var i=0; i < e.childNodes.length; i++)
    {
        if(e.childNodes[i].nodeName == "extraaccounts") {
            e.removeChild(e.childNodes[i]);
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$('[name="extraaccounts"]').remove();

or if you want to change smthing before deleting then

```
$('[name="extraaccounts"]').each(function(index,value){
//do smthing
$(value).remove
});
```

Comment: @Jonah: Are you using jquery or regular javascript?