# How to remove children with the same name from parents with the same name?

Tags: javascript

I have 4 cards(.program-card) and in each one a link(.more-link). I am trying to remove the buttons when the window width > 1024. I know how to remove multiple children with the same name from one parent element but how can this be done with multiple parents that have the same name? Javascript only ideas.

So, removing the children from the DOM is the end goal.

```js
if (window.innerWidth > 1024) {
  const moreLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.more-link'),
    programCards = document.querySelectorAll('.program-card');

  for (let index = 0; index < moreLinks.length; index++) {
    const link = moreLinks[index];

    programCards.forEach(card, () => {
      card.removeChild(link);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section-frame grid-container">
  <div class="program-card">
    <h4>Title 1</h4>
    <img class="card-image" src="./img/asset 4.jpeg" alt="Djeca treniraju">
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique quas ducimus quam soluta sequi suscipit aperiam a.</p>

    <a class="more-link" href="#" title="Saznaj više o programu ''Mali olimpijac''">Saznaj više</a>
  </div>

  <div class="program-card">
    <h4>Title 2</h4>
    <img class="card-image" src="./img/asset 5.jpeg" alt="Djeca treniraju">
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique quas ducimus quam soluta sequi suscipit aperiam a.</p>

    <a class="more-link" href="#" title="Saznaj više o programu ''Mali olimpijac''">Saznaj više</a>
  </div>

  <div class="program-card">
    <h4>Title 3</h4>
    <img class="card-image" src="./img/asset 6.jpeg" alt="Djeca treniraju">
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique quas ducimus quam soluta sequi suscipit aperiam a.</p>

    <a class="more-link" href="#" title="Saznaj više o programu ''Mali olimpijac''">Saznaj više</a>
  </div>

  <div class="program-card">
    <h4>Title 4</h4>
    <img class="card-image" src="./img/asset 7.jpeg" alt="Djeca treniraju">
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique quas ducimus quam soluta sequi suscipit aperiam a.</p>

    <a class="more-link" href="#" title="Saznaj više o programu ''Mali olimpijac''">Saznaj više</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this would help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795103/14657613).

Comment: Saw that post. It's clear how to do it when there's only one parent but I am out of ideas for this 4-parent situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you can do it with media query(css) as well.

```css
.more-link {
        display: block;
    }
    
@media only screen and (min-width : 1024px) {
    .more-link {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

However if you would like with js, here is solution:

```js
function resizedWindow(){
  const moreLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.more-link');
  for (let index = 0; index < moreLinks.length; index++) {
    const link = moreLinks[index];
    if (window.innerWidth > 1024) {
      //or remove -> link.remove();
      link.style.display = 'none'
    } else {
      link.style.display = 'block'
    }
  }
}
window.onresize = resizedWindow;
```

Comment: Should be from specific parent, you are missing .program-card .more-link

Comment: Thanks, I know it can be done via CSS but I'm exercising DOM manipulation so I would like a JS solution.

Comment: Okay, this does the same thing as CSS display: none. My fault, I thought it's gonna be clear from the title of the question and the method I was trying to use in my code, removeChild(), that I want to remove the children from the DOM.

Comment: There is a part in the code sample: `if (window.innerWidth > 1024) { link.remove();} ` will remove all links.

Comment: Yep, I see it now. Thanks. Very elegant solution. I went overly complicated in my thoughts on how to solve it, had 3 times the necessary amount of code...